# Not able to display element back after setting its display to none even though its changed in the code

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to hide the initial list item in my list once I add new item to list through an interface. And I need to show it back once there is no item in my array. What's happening is that I was able to hide it but I am not able to show it again once my array is empty...

```js
const todo = document.querySelector("#todo");
const noItem = document.getElementById("noItem");
const todoList = document.querySelector("#list-container > ul")
let todoArr = [];

checkTodoList = (todoLista) => todoLista.length;
todo.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  let todoItem = todo.value;
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    if (todoItem === "") return alert("Please Enter a todo item");
    checkTodoList(todoArr) == 0 ? noItem.style.display = 'none' : ""
    todoArr.push(todoItem);
    todoList.innerHTML += `<li class="list-item" onclick="checker(this)">${todoItem}<span id="closeBtn" onclick="removeItem(this)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span></i>
       </li>`;
    todo.value = "";
  }
});

checker = (listItem) => {
  listItem.classList.toggle("checked");
}
removeItem = (event) => {
  //remove whitespace from string
  const itemIndex = event.parentElement.textContent.trim();
  //remove item from the array
  todoArr.splice(todoArr.indexOf(itemIndex), 1);
  //remove item from the dom
  event.parentNode.remove();
  //checkTodoList(todoArr)==0?alert("hi"):""
  checkTodoList(todoArr) == 0 ? noItem.style.display = 'block' : ""
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Todo List</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb7f48436a.js"></script>

  <script src='js/main.js' async="async"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Enjoy Your Day</h1>
    <div id="list-container">
      <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="Add item...">
      <div id="input-alert">
        <p>Ooops!Please, enter item </p>
      </div>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class='list-item' id="noItem">No Item in your list </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: checkTodoList(todoArr)==0?noItem.style.display='none':noItem.style.display="block" try that? I haven't run your code this is just a wild guess

Comment: Plz, provide the respective HTML and CSS.

Comment: I just edited the post and added the HTML

Comment: Please elaborate more what the problem is, and what is desired behavior... I made a snippet  for you and do not see any problems with it.

Comment: initially there is list item contain (No item ),once I add an item it should have display of none. And once the array of todo items is 0 then it should come back again. Whats facing is that this initial item is hiding once I add an item , but when the array of items is 0 its not redisplaying again on DOM

Answer (score 0):

I added this into your removeItem function:

```
  if (document.querySelectorAll("ul.list li:not(#noItem)").length < 1) {
    document.querySelector("#noItem").style.display = "";
  }
```

And this into todo.addEventListener("keypress", (event)

```
 if (document.querySelectorAll("ul.list li:not(#noItem)").length > 0) {
    document.querySelector("#noItem").style.display = "none";
  }
```

It could be done maybe differently but I don't want to analyze your whole code.

This simply checks when you press remove item if there are any li items in list other then #noitem, if not, show #noitem. Same goes for adding items, if there is more then 1 li item, remove #noitem...

```js
const todo = document.querySelector("#todo");
const noItem = document.getElementById("noItem");
const todoList = document.querySelector("#list-container > ul")
let todoArr = [];

checkTodoList = (todoLista) => todoLista.length;
todo.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  let todoItem = todo.value;
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    if (todoItem === "") return alert("Please Enter a todo item");
    checkTodoList(todoArr) == 0 ? noItem.style.display = 'none' : ""
    todoArr.push(todoItem);
    todoList.innerHTML += `<li class="list-item" onclick="checker(this)">${todoItem}<span id="closeBtn" onclick="removeItem(this)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span></i>
       </li>`;
    todo.value = "";
  }
  
    if (document.querySelectorAll("ul.list li:not(#noItem)").length > 0) {
    document.querySelector("#noItem").style.display = "none";
  }
  
});

checker = (listItem) => {
  listItem.classList.toggle("checked");
}
removeItem = (event) => {
  //remove whitespace from string
  const itemIndex = event.parentElement.textContent.trim();
  //remove item from the array
  todoArr.splice(todoArr.indexOf(itemIndex), 1);
  //remove item from the dom
  event.parentNode.remove();
  //checkTodoList(todoArr)==0?alert("hi"):""
  checkTodoList(todoArr) == 0 ? noItem.style.display = 'block' : "";


  if (document.querySelectorAll("ul.list li:not(#noItem)").length < 1) {
    document.querySelector("#noItem").style.display = "";
  } 

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Todo List</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb7f48436a.js"></script>

  <script src='js/main.js' async="async"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <h1>Enjoy Your Day</h1>
    <div id="list-container">
      <input type="text" name="todo" id="todo" placeholder="Add item...">
      <div id="input-alert">
        <p>Ooops!Please, enter item </p>
      </div>
      <ul class="list">
        <li class='list-item' id="noItem">No Item in your list </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```